# Is it possible to create a new, assignable attribute for pygame.Rect objects?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to be able to set the center coordinate of a Rect object equal to a tuple the same way one would go about setting any of the corner coordinates or the coordinates for the midpoints of any of the sides equal to a tuple, which would be to assign the value to the appropriate Rect attribute using code that looks something like this:

```
a_rectangle = pygame.Rect(ValueForX, ValueForY, width, height) #creates Rect object with top-left corner at (ValueForX, ValueForY)
a_rectangle.topleft = (DifferentX, DifferentY) #sets top-left corner coordinates to (DifferentX, DifferentY)
```

To my knowledge, there is no pre-existing attribute for the center of a Rect object--see [here](https://inventwithpython.com/invent4thed/chapter17.html#calibre_link-108)--so instead of using the above code, I have to use code that looks something like this:

```
a_rectangle = pygame.Rect(ValueForX, ValueForY, width, height) #creates Rect object with top-left corner at (ValueForX, ValueForY)
a_rectangle.centerx = Xvalue #sets x-value for the center coordinate to Xvalue
a_rectangle.centery = Yvalue #sets y-value for the center coordinate to Yvalue
```

Since, depending on the program, it's not exactly as simple as picking a few numbers out of a hat and being done with it, I'd rather be able to use fewer lines of code so that I don't end up with a mess on my hands.

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a new attribute for the center coordinate of a Rect object, and, if so, how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rect has `center`

```
a_rectangle.center = (X, Y)
```

To center element in window or center text on button

```
a_rectangle.center = window.center
text.center = button.center
```

See official documentation: [Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

```
x,y
top, left, bottom, right
topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
center, centerx, centery
size, width, height
w,h
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you need new functions or variables in `Rect` then you can create own class based on `Rect` and add own functions. And later use your class instead of `Rect`

```
import math
import pygame

class MyRect(pygame.Rect):

    @property    
    def area(self):
        return self.width * self.height

    @area.setter
    def area(self, value):
        self.width = self.height = int(math.sqrt(value))

a_rectangle = MyRect(0, 0, 10, 10) 
print( a_rectangle.center )

print( a_rectangle.area ) # 100
print( a_rectangle.width, a_rectangle.height ) # 10, 10

a_rectangle.area = 144

print( a_rectangle.area ) # 144
print( a_rectangle.width, a_rectangle.height ) # 12, 12
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that--the website I was looking at was for the online textbook I used when I first started learning Python. Thanks for the help!

Comment: this can be also good: [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/)